# C++: basic questions on methods & "already has a body" errors

Tags: c++, function, methods, compiler-errors

I'm working on a program that takes a very large block of seconds and attempts to break them up into days, hours, minutes, and seconds.  Being new to C++, I'm attempting to split this problem up into 3 methods: main (intakes seconds from user, and passes findings onto 'calculation'), calculation (attempts to divide value by days/hours/minutes, and pass those onto 'results'), & results (which prints out results).

Currently I'm having and issue where the compiler returns:

> error C2084: function 'void calculation(__int64)' already has a body

In addition to that I've been looking around and have noticed a lot of people using 'header files' when dealing with this stuff; so my second question would be is that necessary and are there any ways to avoid it (I have to submit only 1 .cpp file, so anything outside of my main file has to be out of the question).

Below is my code so far,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


//method declarations
void calculation(long long int value) {};
void results(int days, int hours, int mins, int secs) {};


int main()
{
   //Declaration
   long long int seconds;
   

   //user prompt
   cout << "Enter seconds" << endl;
   cin >> seconds;


   //check for valid input
   if (seconds > 0)
   {
      cout << endl << "Total seconds: " << seconds;

      calculation(seconds);
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Total seconds must be greater than zero";
   }

}


void calculation(long long int value)
{
   //divisor values
   const int secToDay = 86400;
   const int secToHour = 3600;
   const int secToMin = 60;

   //calculated vars
   int d, h, m, s;

   
   //calculating if there are any days in this
   d = value / secToDay;

   if (d != 0)
      value -= (secToDay * d);

   //calculating if there's any hours
   h = value / secToHour;

   if (h != 0)
      value -= (secToHour * h);

   //calculating minutes
   m = value / secToMin;

   if (m != 0)
      value -= (secToMin * m);

   //whatever's left over goes to seconds
   s = value;


   results(d, h, m, s);
}


void results(int days, int hours, int mins, int secs)
{
   cout << days << " day(s)" << endl;
   cout << hours << " hours(s)" << endl;
   cout << mins << " minute(s)" << endl;
   cout << secs << " second(s)" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and enable all warnings and debug info in it (e.g. compile using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  if using GCC). Then read also the documentation of your debugger (e.g. of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: `void calculation(long long int value) {};` is not a declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `{}` from your declaration.

---

### Definition

```cpp
void results(int days, int hours, int mins, int secs) {};
```

This is called a **function definition**.

A c++ function definition tells the compiler the actual body of the function. A function definition is also a declaration.

Consider this to be the same as

```cpp
void results(int days, int hours, int mins, int secs) 
{
   
}
```

Note: You don't need a semicolon `;` after function definitions

---

### Declaration

```cpp
void results(int days, int hours, int mins, int secs);
```

This is a **function declaration**.

A function declaration tells the compiler the name, return type, and parameters of a function. A function declaration is *not* a definition.

To let your code compile properly, change your **definition** into a **declaration**.

---

In short, remove the `{}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the distinction you're making (which is in the link you post) between declaration and definition is incorrect.   In the C++ standard,  a definition is not something completely distinct from a declaration - it is a particular type of declaration   (i.e. all definitions ARE declarations,  but not all declarations are definitions).

Comment: @Peter Yeah that is true, but how much can I add to the post really? The answer was directed towards his question and hence I have given an external link too.

Comment: What @Peter is saying is correct. You don't need to change much to fix that, so I added the lines (and made some formatting edits as well). Also, I removed the external link, as the answer nicely covers what is relevant to the OP's question.